# Get usr/local path in mac osx

Tags: xcode

I want to get the "usr/local" path on mac. How to get this path. Is there any standard function for it.
Do i need to use the environment variable for this or is there any other way.

Comment: /usr/local is just /usr/local. Can you give some context?

Comment: In window we have GetWindowsDirectory() function which inbuilt..same like that is there any function in mac that will return me the usr/local path, i want to get the file stored at that location, remaining path is hard code. e.g file:///usr/local/Database/setup/config.txt.. i want to get path till usr/local using standard function remaining path will be hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local is just a Unix convention, not something recognized by OS X. `NSHomeDirectory` (defined in `NSPathUtilities.h`) will get you the user's home directory (`~/`) if you aren't sandboxed. But if you want /usr/local just use /usr/local.

Comment: NSPathUtilities.h file is use for coco , but i want it for carbon xcode.

Comment: FSRef     f;
FSFindFolder( kUserDomain, kUsersFolderType, kDontCreateFolder, &f );
CFURLRef  url = CFURLCreateFromFSRef( 0, &f );
PMString folderPath (GetPathFromCFURLRef(url).c_str());                                    This gives the path of "/users" i want path of "/usr/local".